Why is only the first call frame aliased on Optimism?
Because addresses can be impersonated cross-chain, rollups have to alias addresses when L1 to L2 transactions are performed.
From Optimism's docs:

CALLER
msg.sender
If the transaction is an L1 ⇒ L2 transaction triggered by a smart contract on L1, and this is the first call frame (rather than an internal transaction from one contract to another), the same address aliasing behavior applies.

Why is the address aliased only within first call frames and not internal txs, too?
